# Pass Page.Request to a Web Service?

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, http, httprequest

Is it possible to pass a `Page.Request` object to a Web Service?

I need a Web Service to provide data to a browser client, but I cannot retrieve this data without an object that requires `Page.Request` in the signature.

The alternative seems to be creating pages that take parameters in a query string and calling them with $.get(), which seems over the top.

Comment: I don't know if you are talking about a legacy web service (ASMX) or a WCF-based service exposed over HTTP, but in both cases you can get your own Request object inside the services.

Comment: It's a WCF service. It doesn't seem to be as simple as `HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();` How would I do that?

Comment: I added a sample pulled from working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the request is made over HTTP (which isn't always the case with a WCF endpoint), you can simply use `HttpContext.Current.Request` in your code.

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements( RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed )]
public class MyService {

    [OperationContract]
    public string Foo() {

        var request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Simple answer. Unfortunately this doesn't work in this context, in that it does return a proper object, but it's missing some `Request.Form` data. However, that wasn't part of my query, so I've marked it correct.

Comment: Are you sending the data with an HTTP POST? if not, that could cause the Request.Form collection to be empty.

Comment: It's complicated. It's a SharePoint app hosted in the cloud, and a series of tokens are sent to the app when you click on it. It appears these tokens do not persist past the first page load.

Comment: Understood. In that case, maybe a HTTP/TCP sniffer would be useful to see what is being sent (and when).

Comment: Thanks for going above and beyond, Tim. Reddit Gold for you!